# Location of attachments in JIRA

Tags: jira

Where does JIRA saves the attachments related to tickets? 
I want to backup only the screen-shot images and documents found on my JIRA site.
Does it save it in MySQL BLOB column types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [JRA-23758](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23758) (now duplicate of [JRA-19873](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-19873)):

At current state, attachments in JIRA are stored inside attachments/project-name, in the hierarchy below:

```
- attachments
 |- project-name
   |- issue key
```

That is actually an issue:

> Since attachments are associated with issue keys, this could pose a problem for those on a Linux/UNIX platform. The ext3 filesystem can only have a maximum of 32,000 subdirectories per directory. The ext4 filesystem has fixed this limitation and increase its size to 64,000 subdirectories per directory.
>
> The problem creeps in when you have 65,000 issues per project. If this was the case, then JIRA would not be able to save any more attachments and this would be problematic.

Comment: Only if every one of the 32K issues in a project has an attachment. Confluence changed its on-disk structure to avoid this, IIRC.

Comment: Any update for the same question for the latest version of Jira (5.1.7) ? Are attachments saved in DB?

Comment: @Lin Are attachment saved on DB? I don't think so, since there is an enhancement related to that point: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-29380

Comment: Atlassian have resolved the issue above without comment, meaning it won't be done.

Answer (score 3):

Jira stores files in the filesystem, but stores a **reference** to the attachements in the database (table **fileattachment**). That reference includes the file name, MIME type, author, size, etc.

For example, the attachment **image7.png** linked to project WHATEVER, issue WHATEVER-7, would be stored in the table fileattachment under, say, ID 10654; that would translate in the filesystem as:

/YOUR_JIRA_HOME_FOLDER/data/attachments/WHATEVER/WHATEVER-7/10654

where 10654 is the actual attachment, and references the ID of the file in the database.

Comment: Much more informative than above answer (was looking for database table), thanks!